# React Native iOS release white screen with TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.default')

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

My team's react native app works great in `debug mode` but when I run for `release` or `upload to TestFlight` the app is just a white screen. The output I get in XCode is this:

```
TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.default')

This error is located at:
    in k
    in L
    in p
    in RCTView
    in Portal.Host
    in n
    in c
    in s
    in n
    in RCTView
    in RCTView
    in c
```

This is my bundle command:

```
react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ./app/assets
```

> I haven't had this issue with this project in the past.

Using these versions:

```
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.59.10",
```

I've tried about a million different solutions but so far no luck! Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

**UPDATE**

When I put in a  it displays fine. But as soon as I bring in anything with react-navigation like createAppContainer or createDrawerNavigator it just shows a blank white screen and that error. Again, this only applying to release mode. Not sure what the issue is, but it is definitely with react-navigation.

Comment: I had the same issue and in my case its referring a property of an object which was undefined, better check your JS code for any undefined properties or variables

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan Cool so I guess there's no way to know exactly which variable that is? And your error was the same? (t.default) and the RCTView?

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan I've discovered it's with react-navigation. Any similarities with you there?

Comment: no it doenst say which variable it is, i use react native navigation